# External hard disk not mounted and not seen when plugged to Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd, devices

Suddenly Ubuntu stopped recognizing my external USB drive HDD, this is my `dmesg` output:

````
[ 2341.271570] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd
[ 2341.293118] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=61b7, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 2341.293124] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2341.293127] usb 2-2: Product: M3 Portable
[ 2341.293130] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 2341.293132] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NM16MJES
[ 2341.298445] scsi host0: uas
[ 2341.299044] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  M3 Portable      9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2341.299610] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 2341.299677] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[ 2342.327359] .........ready
[ 2350.520260] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 7814037167 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[ 2380.803498] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 2380.803505] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#28 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 3f 00 04 00
[ 2380.819515] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 2385.911672] usb 2-2: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 2391.032068] usb 2-2: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 2396.408029] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2401.784107] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2401.991975] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 43, error -62
[ 2407.416231] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2412.791882] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2412.999714] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 43, error -62
[ 2418.423929] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2423.799973] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2424.007851] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 43, error -62
[ 2429.432025] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2434.808053] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2435.016277] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 43, error -62
[ 2435.032593] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED err -19
[ 2435.032604] sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 2435.032702] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 43
[ 2435.032706] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 2435.032712] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 2435.032737] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2435.032749] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2435.032754] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 2435.032758] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2435.032763] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2435.032770] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2435.032776] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2435.032783] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[ 2435.360075] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2435.360080] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[ 2435.604094] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2435.604098] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[ 2435.700129] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2436.019969] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2441.464104] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2446.840411] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2447.048394] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 44, error -62
[ 2452.476053] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2457.848194] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2458.056133] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 45, error -62
[ 2458.064124] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 2464.248171] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2469.624166] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 2469.832177] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 46, error -62```
````

Could someone advise me how to troubleshoot this and at least recover my data?

If I run `sudo lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 048: ID 0bc2:61b7 Seagate RSS LLC <---------------- This is the device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:565a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But I don't see it within `/dev/`.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: output of `lsbusb` and `lsblk`:

```
energo@ENE018:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bc2:61b7 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:565a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

energo@ENE018:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/288
loop1         7:1    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/100
loop2         7:2    0 217,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop3         7:3    0 151,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/59
loop4         7:4    0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop5         7:5    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/91
loop6         7:6    0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop7         7:7    0 178,4M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/2131
loop8         7:8    0   2,7M  1 loop /snap/telegram-cli/25
loop9         7:9    0  97,7M  1 loop /snap/core/10126
loop10        7:10   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop11        7:11   0  35,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop12        7:12   0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/826
loop13        7:13   0   2,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
loop14        7:14   0    61M  1 loop /snap/core20/634
loop15        7:15   0  53,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/970
loop16        7:16   0   276K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/570
loop17        7:17   0 142,8M  1 loop /snap/code/48
loop18        7:18   0  55,3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop19        7:19   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop20        7:20   0  88,4M  1 loop /snap/core/6964
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   790M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     5G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 471,2G  0 part /
```

EDIT 2:

I have opened the disk, here is a video showing what happens when I plug it: https://streamable.com/25ays1

Comment: Check it with another computer.

Comment: Tried with Mac and Windows, same problem: disk not seen. Any idea?

Comment: please [edit] your question to paste to output of lsblk (while usbhdd is plugged)

Comment: @cmak.fr Please, check my edit, I have added the output of lsblk.

Comment: From the output, it seems that `lsblk` doesn't see the external hdd, I can't find it in the list, it's a 4TB hard disk... Also, after some time while the disk is plugged, if I rerun the `sudo lsusb` command, I don't see it in the output anymore. Any idea? I really need to at least recover the data stored in it, thank you!

Comment: this looks like hardware failure of ur usb device or data cable. for data recovery you may remove the hdd out of the enclosure and plug it in a new one

Comment: OK, thank you, will try it.

Comment: Guys, please, check my edit, I have opened the drive to check the disk, what do you think? Thank you!

Comment: @cmak.fr Is there a video or a tutorial explaining how to do it? Cause' it would be the first time for me. Thank you!

Comment: try a different cable first, it's the most common issue with externals.

Comment: @rtaft I have tried to remote the USB 3 connector and plug it into a new SATA connector, but that didn't help... Same problem, what else can I do? Switching the motherboard?